# How to make an Alias for a server in SSMS (MSSQL Tools18)

Tags: sql-server, ssms, rename, alias

I am wondering about something. I work with a lof of SQL servers, to which I need to connect several times a day. Unfortunately there are quite a lot of them and I constantly need to check the IPs and select them by IPs. Each server belongs to a different customer, none are mine and none are local.

what I'm looking for is the ability to give them names/aliases in my SSMS application, so that when I go to connect Object explorer and get the server login screen, I don't have under "server name" a list of IP addresses, but names/aliases, that I create for my purposes only. Just as a display option, so that others' ability to connect to the servers or use them remains completely unaffected. So that instead of having a bunch of 192.168........., I could see for example: "Cust1_Prod, Cust2_Prod, Cust1_Test, Cust2_Test" aliases as I please.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at SQL aliases? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/create-or-delete-a-server-alias-for-use-by-a-client?view=sql-server-ver15. This however would also allow clients to connect.

Comment: What do you mean clients to connect?

Comment: I believe clients will be able to use the alias as well.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to leverage the [`Registered Server`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/register-servers/register-servers?view=sql-server-ver15) functionality for this.

In the toolbar, View -> Registered Servers. Pin the window that opens up.

You can create folders for more organization if you like.

Right click on a folder name and click `New Server Registration`. In the dialog box that opens, you can give each server whatever name you prefer. In this case, I put "My Custom Name for This Server" in the box.

[image]

From this list, you can right click the server name and click on `Object Explorer` to open the connection. In your OE window, your custom name shows up, followed by the actual name of the box.

[image]

These names get saved to your local config files. You can export them when you get a new machine, or if you want to share with your team, but it's strictly a local SSMS rename.

Also, once you have some servers registered, you can right click on a folder and select `Object Explorer` and it will open connections to all of the servers in the folder. I use that trick to cluster my Dev, UAT, and Prod boxes together, but if there are groups of servers you frequently use together, this is a quick way to get to them all with one click.